# Find every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f = X^{2n+1} - (2n+1)X + a$ has a repeated root

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If we inspect its derivative

$$f'=(2n+1)X^{2n} - (2n+1) = (2n+1)(X^{2n}-1)$$

we can deduce that

$$f'(w) = 0 \ \iff \  (w^{n})^{2} = 1 \ \iff \ w^n = 1 \  \ \text{or} \ \ w^n = -1$$

This means that $w \in G_n$ is an nth root of unity. Accordingly,

$$f(w) = w.(w^n)^2 - (2n+1)w + a = 0 \ \iff \ a = 2nw$$

Since $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we know that $a$ can only be $\pm 2n$,

**Question.** Suppose we drop the restriction $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and admit complex coefficients. What's up with the case when $w^n = -1$? If $n$ is odd, then $w$ can only be $-1$, right? But what happens when $n$ is even? Does it still hold that $w$ is an nth root of unity?

Comment: Hint: $(w^n)^2 = 1 \iff w^{2n} = 1$. Think $2n$th roots of unity instead.

Comment: As you've mentioned we have: 
$$f'(w) = 0 \ \iff \  w^{2n} = 1 \ \iff \ w \  \ \text{is a} \ \ 2n^{\text{th}} \ \text{root of unity}.$$ 

This means
$$f(w) = w.(w^{2n}) - (2n+1)w + a = 0 \ \iff \ a = 2nw,$$ 
where $w \  \ \text{is a} \ \ 2n^{\text{th}} \ \text{root of unity},$ and this is all the complex possibilities. 

Also, note that the only roots of unity which are real, are $\pm1$. so the only real possibilities are $\pm 2n$.